# Compare the efficient between neural network and bayesian network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, bayesian-networks, supervised-learning

Like the title, could anyone tell me the ANN and the Bayesian which is better in classify or detection and recognition issue ? 
In radar tracking system, the target have speed, orientation, height,... which can be apply ?
In image processing system, which can be apply ?

Comment: This is not a site to put your homework questions on. Please stop asking blatantly off-topic questions (like your one about VirtualBox that got 12 upvotes): There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be no absolute "A is better than B" answer to a such question. The performance of each system depends how the data are situated in the problem space, and in different problems some algorithms are more suitable than others.

That being said, if you want to select a machine learning method for a practical application, the best solution is using support vector machines, which seem to produce the best results in most problems. This is especially true in image processing, where the number of attributes describing the image is usually large, and SVMs are the standard approach.